# How to go to each directory and execute a name-dependent command?

Tags: bash, terminal, directory, exec

I have a folder that contains several sub-folders, and each sub-folder contains a `*.nii` file.
The directory structure is:

```
parent_directory
 - JACK (folders are titled as first-names)
    - *.nii (each .nii file is named a random unique combination of letters&numbers)
 - JILL
    - *.nii
 - JOE
    - *.nii
 - JANE
    - *.nii
```

I want to execute this command:

```
fslreorient2std input output
```

The "input" must be the name of the `.nii` file, and ideally I want the output to be named `or_*.nii`.

How can I `cd` to each subfolder in my directory, and execute this command where I place "input" as the unique name of the `*.nii` file in each subfolder?
Thank you!

Comment: See [understanding-the-exec-option-of-find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)

Answer (score 0):

Untested, using just one loop and bash *parameter expansion*:

```
cd parent_directory
for file in J*/*.nii; do
    ( cd $(dirname "$file") && fslreorient2std "${file##*/}" "or_${file##*/}" )
done
```

The `( )` create a *subshell*, that way, each call to `cd` start from `parent_directory`

Answer (score 0):

Use nested loops. The outer loop iterates over the subdirectories. It performs `cd` in a subshell so that it automatically returns to the original shell when done.

The inner loop iterates over the `*.nii` files, adding the `or_` prefix to produce the output filename.

```
for dir in */
do (
    cd "$dir"
    for file in *.nii
    do
        fslreorient2std "$file" "or_$file"
    done
)
done
```